# can SimpleDB store binary attributes?

Tags: binary, nosql, amazon-simpledb

can [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) (Amazon AWS) store binary attributes? I'm familiar with the max size of 1024 bytes /attribute. The usecase will be to store compressed strings as attributes and use SimpleDB to do lookups for multiple keys at once. More specifically: multiple item-keys are queried at once, while requesting to return the same column for each of the item-keys.

Is this (storing binary attributes in SimpleDB) supported?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB has better support for binary datatypes and for what you are thinking of use.

Comment: 'better support' does that mean SimpleDB doesn't support binary datatypes? I'm fully aware of DynamoDB but SimpleDB is enough for me all other things considered, as well as being far cheaper for my particular use-case.